# Analytic solution of the heat equation with a source term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I have the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions
$$u_t(t,x)=u_{xx}(t,x)+\sin(x)$$
$$u(t,0)=u(t,2\pi)=0$$
$$u(0,x)=u_0(x)$$
Now, without the source term I could write the solution as
$$u(t,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin(n\pi x)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}$$
where
$$B_n=2\int_0^{2\pi}u_0(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx$$
but I'm not sure what it looks like with a source term. I had a problem set question which assumed knowledge of the solution to show it converges to it's stationary form, so I'm guessing it can be derived using the homogenous equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $f(x) = \sin x$ solves
\begin{align}
f_{xx}+\sin x = 0,
\end{align}
with the given boundary conditions, that is, $f$ is a stationary solution to the above problem.

Next, consider the function $v=u-f$ where $u$ solves the above heat equation. Then, we see that
\begin{align}
v_t-v_{xx} = u_t-u_{xx}+f''= \sin x+f'' = 0.
\end{align}

Here, we see that $v$ measures how $u$ deviates from the stationary solution $f$. The above calculation demonstrates that the deviation satisfies a heat equation that converges to zero given the boundary conditions. In short, $u$ converges to $f$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the $\sin x$ source term is time independent: what happens if you add $t \sin x$ to your solution?
does it respect the PDE ? and the boundary conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that since you're on $[0,2\pi]$, the appropriate argument of the eigenfunctions is not $n \pi x$. This is not just a minor technicality since it affects how you must deal with the forcing.

Once you get that straight, consider the evolution equation for the $n$th Fourier coefficient (obtained by multiplying both sides by the $n$th eigenfunction and integrating, and pulling the time derivative out of the first term). You should find that all but one of them are just of the form $\frac{d}{dt} \hat{u}_n + \lambda_n u_n = 0$ (which is what you see in the homogeneous heat equation) while the $n=1$ equation is of the form $\frac{d}{dt} \hat{u}_1 + \lambda_1 u_1 = c$. This latter ODE is simple enough that you can just solve it.